# Choose deep or shallow JSON serialization in Grails

Tags: json, grails

Is there a way to easily specify whether to convert an object as JSON in a deep or shallow manner? I know you can configure the grails.converters.JSON utility in the Config.groovy file by specifying something like the following:

```
grails.converters.json.default.deep = true
```

but when I convert certain objects, I don't want to deep convert.

I also saw that somebody recommended using JSON.use("deep"), but I get the following error:

```
Error 2012-03-04 00:39:13,673 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalAccessException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Quaffic/home/json
Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone with modifiers "public". Stacktrace follows:
Message: Class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.joda.time.tz.DateTimeZoneBuilder$PrecalculatedZone with modifiers "public"
   Line | Method
->> 198 | value          in grails.converters.JSON
```

It seems like it could be a joda.time error, but this doesn't happen when I just use the plain Config.groovy technique. Kind of confusing...

Any help would be great!

Comment: I got the same issue. It doesn't seem that the joda-time converters from the joda-time plugin are invoked after `JSON.use("deep")`. They are if you register them manually though. JSON.use("deep") JodaConverters.registerJsonAndXmlMarshallers() I'll let you know if I figure something better out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution was to not rely on deep/shallow json generation. I created a map, inserted elements, and serialized that. Probably not the best practice, but it gets the job done.

Comment: did the same, must be a better way.