# Grails - collection propery don't get rendered to JSON/XML

Tags: xml, json, grails

I have domain class that has a collection type property. I'd like to render it to JSON, or XML but it won't show. I don't know why that's so.

Here's an example:

```
class Bag {

    List things

}
```

But it only renders (in JSON) as:

```
{"class":"com.mystuff.Bag","id":null}
```

even if I put objects in the list. Where do I check for problems?

#### Update 1

I tried doing the same thing on another project and I can see the list getting marshalled to JSON with no additional configuration. The other project is a test one using more vanilla settings. I don't remember changing much config on the actual project though.

#### Update 2

So I was testing the code and found out that JSON marshalling works fine with collections, until I place the domain class inside `@Mock`, like `@Mock(Bag)`. I'm not sure why this is happening. I assume whatever `@Mock` does with domain classes, `grails run-app` does as well.

Comment: You may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552672/choose-deep-or-shallow-json-serialization-in-grails

Comment: Even after using `JSON.use('deep')`, the list won't still show.

Comment: I've tried and failed to use `as JSON` in tests too. In controllers and services it works, but while using it in test classes I'm getting exceptions like `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Unconvertable Object of class: [any class]`